# How to print all strings in a list on one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list filled with strings and I need to print all the strings, on one line, one after the other. Is there a method or function to do this? I've tried just printing the list but that also prints the square brackets around it and includes the apostrophes and commas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ?

```
lis = ['A', 'Quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jump', 'over', 'the', 'lazy']
print(' '.join(lis))
```

Output:

```
A Quick brown fox jump over the lazy
```